# Reading all buffers except for the last one (in C)

Tags: c

I want to read all buffers from a pipe except for the last one. This is my current code:

```
while(read(server_to_client,serverString2,sizeof(serverString2))){
   printf("Client : PID %d",getpid());
   printf("-Target>>%s<<", clientString2);
   printf(serverString2);
}
```

The problem with that is it reads everything from the buffer. How can I avoid reading the last buffer?

Comment: So how does your software recognize the 'next-to-the-last' buffer?

Comment: The software is just reading all the buffers from the server side in a loop instead of one-by-one. It does not recognize anything else

Comment: `printf(serverString2);` is a **very bad** habit. What happens if there is a `%` in the string ? what happens if there happens to be no NUL character after the buffer ? NOTE `read()` can return -1, which will **not** cause the loop to exit.

Comment: I deal with all the checks on the server side. I am just using the client to print the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The question does not even make sense.

The question supposes that a "buffer" is a meaningful unit of measure for your data, but it is not.  In particular, the third argument to **read**(2) is a *maximum* number of bytes to read, but the call may actually transfer fewer bytes for a large number reasons, with reaching the end of the data being only one.  Other reasons are in fact a lot more likely to manifest when the file descriptor being read is connected to a pipe, as you say yours is, than when it is connected to a file.  Note that this means you must *always* capture `read()`'s return value if you intend to examine the data it reads, for otherwise you cannot know how much of the buffer contains valid data.

More generally, you cannot tell from an open file descriptor for a pipe how much data is available to be read from it.  You need to include that information in your protocol (for example, HTTP's `Content-Length` header), or somehow communicate it out-of-band.  That still doesn't tell you how much data is available to be read *right now*, but it can help you determine when to stop trying to read more.

---

**Edited to add:**

If you ask because you want to avoid dealing with partially-filled buffers, then you are flat out of luck.  At minimum you need to be prepared for a partially-filled buffer when the data are prematurely truncated.  Unless the total size of the data to be transferred is certain to be a multiple of the chosen buffer size, you will also have to be prepared to deal with a partial buffer at the end of your data.  You can, however, avoid dealing with partial buffers in the middle of your data by repeatedly `read()`ing until you fill the buffer, perhaps via a wrapper function such as this:

```
ssize_t read_fully(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    char *byte_buf = buf;
    ssize_t bytes_remaining = count;

    while (1) {
        ssize_t nread = read(fd, byte_buf, bytes_remaining);

        if ((nread <= 0) || ((bytes_remaining -= nread) <= 0)) {
            break;
        }
        byte_buf += nread;
        bytes_remaining -= nread;
    }

    return count - bytes_remaining;
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can approach the problem altogether differently.  Instead of trying to avoid reading certain data, you may be able to read it but avoid *processing* it.  Whether that could be sensible depends on the nature of your program.

Comment: How am I supposed to about avoiding processing the last buffer?

Comment: C offers a flexible suite of conditional statements.  Any one of them could be employed to avoid processing the last buffer (the same way) provided you can solve the key problem of *identifying* the last one (possibly after reading it).

Comment: If you don't know either out-of-band or from something in the protocol how long to expect the data to be, then you cannot know before you've reached the end that you are about to reach it.  If it is essential to have that knowledge then your best bet may be to cache the whole transmission in memory or on disk to count its size, then process it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to avoid **reading** the last buffer? Or just avoid doing anything with it? Perhaps a different form of loop? Perhaps a check for eof() after reading each buffer?

```
while(read(server_to_client,serverString2,sizeof(serverString2)))
{
   if (! eof(server_to_client))
   {
      printf("Client : PID %d",getpid());
      printf("-Target>>%s<<", clientString2);
      printf(serverString2);
   }
   else
   {
      // do special stuff for the last buffer here
   }
}
```

Comment: I need to print the last buffer in a different way. I just want the last buffer to produce a different result

Comment: So, put an else after the if clause which I added (nvm, I updated my answer for you)